# Simulate a label for command similar to GOTO

Tags: javascript

I have read that in JavaScript there is no `GOTO` command or `label` tags as in other programming languages.

For this, some have used `while` or `for` loops and others have used `switch`.

In my particular case I want to simulate a label called for example `A:` and then simulate a `GOTO` to that label.

I share the code outline so you can see what I mean.

I don't want to go to the `this.refreshHistoric` function but to the `XMLHttpRequest`

```
this.refreshHistoric = function (info, n) {
        
        //Here label A:
        
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4) { 
                
                if (this.status === 200) {
                //do some things
                } else if (this.status === 404) { 
                     //define some variables and GOTO label A:  
                
                }
            
            }
        }
        xhttp.open('GET', proxy_URL + itunes_api + urlencode(artistHist) + ' ' + urlencode(songHist) + '&media=music&limit=1.', true);
        xhttp.send();
}
```

Actually I want to do something more complex without having to create a new function.

If a 404 error occurs what I want to do is send `GET` again without `proxy_URL` variable
In other words, the new `GET` would be like this:

```
xhttp.open('GET', itunes_api + urlencode(artistHist) + ' ' + urlencode(songHist) + '&media=music&limit=1.', true);
```

I can do this perfectly by creating a new function, but to save code I want to see if it is possible to redefine `GET` and in passing I learn to simulate a `GOTO - Label` in JavaScript. :)

Comment: Not having a `goto` is a feature.

Comment: In this case a `goto` wouldn't even be possible. That's a callback function. The surrounding scope doesn't exist to "go to".

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to simulate something similar, or if a 404 happens redefine the `GET` without creating a new function. I just edited the question with more data so you can see what I mean by redefining the `GET`.

Comment: Sometimes 404 error happens from using a proxy, I want to try to send the same `GET` without the proxy to see what happens.

Comment: Why worry about creating a new function? They're cheap and the best approach in a lot of cases.

Comment: Ok I'll try by creating a new function with new `GET`. I appreciate you improved my code with the arrow function. +10

Comment: Arrow functions are especially important inside objects because they preserve `this` and make your code a lot more friendly. Worth using whenever you can!

Comment: This code is old, arrow functions did not exist yet, but it is good to update and learn. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to think in terms of asynchronous code, where these functions run at different times, and not in terms of linear, sequential code like you might be used to.

That function executes at a distant point in the future and the surrounding scope is long gone save for what ends up captured by the various closure(s) involved.

The general approach to have a "retry" in code like this is to define a function you can call again:

```
this.refreshHistoric = (info, n) => {
  const makeRequest = () => {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) { 
        switch (this.status) {
          case 200:
            //do some things
            break;
          case 404:
            // Define some variables...

            // Schedule a retry a moment later to avoid flooding the service
            setInterval(makeRequest, 1000);
            break;
        }
      }
    }

    xhttp.open(`GET ${proxy_URL}${itunes_api}${urlencode(artistHist)}  ${urlencode(songHist)}&media=music&limit=1.`, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }

  makeRequest();
}
```

Note that I've cleaned this up to use template strings, avoiding a lot of messy concatenation, and to use the new arrow-style function definition, which results i reduced clutter.

Comment: There is something wrong with template strings.
I have changed the first character from ` to ' because  code did not close and it affected other lines. See screenshot: https://gifyu.com/image/gL1g
I also tried closing the code with the same ` character: https://gifyu.com/image/gL18
But in both cases it gives an error: `script.js:154 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'GET ${proxy_URL}${itunes_api}${urlencode(artistHist)}  ${urlencode(songHist)}&media=music&limit=1.' is not a valid HTTP method.`   Could it be because `urlencode` is a function?

Comment: It should be a backtick, but I made a mistake and didn't close it with one as well. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more details on how they work.

Comment: I did think it was a typo, but I corrected it both ways and neither worked.

Comment: I already read the documentation and you are right it uses ` to open and close but for some reason it does not work. Don't worry I went back to the previous concatenation and I already got it working.

Comment: It will work if it's corrected. You should experiment some more with that because it's often way easier to deal with than concatenation.